# Discord bot enter the voice channel, but it doesn't play any audio

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, distube

My discord bot that i'm creating it doesn't play any audio when he joins a voice channel, this is my code.

What i want it is to get the youtube url from the message and plays it. (I'm totally new to javascript so idk if the code is right?)

```
const { Distube } = require('distube')
const distube = require('distube').Distube
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer } = require('@discordjs/voice')
const player = createAudioPlayer()

module.exports = (client) => {

    const targetChannelId = '431197967337390081'
    const prefix = '-'
    
    client.on('messageCreate', msg => {

        if (msg.channel.id === targetChannelId) {
            if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
                const command = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ')[0]
                const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ')[1]

                if (command === 'play') {
                    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                        channelId: msg.member.voice.channel.id,
                        guildId: '354279496502738947',
                        adapterCreator: msg.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
                    }).subscribe(audioPlayer)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This violates youtube's ToS, please don't do this.

"The following restrictions apply to your use of the Service. You are not allowed to... use the Service to view or listen to Content other than for personal, non-commercial use (for example, you may not publicly screen videos or stream music from the Service)"

You can see youtube ToS [here](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) and the API Terms [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service)

Comment: Odd. I've been having the same issue for the past few months and eventually just gave up. I wasn't using `distube` though, so I suspect it is an issue with `@discordjs/voice`.

Comment: Also, the [discordjs/voice GitHub repo](https://github.com/discordjs/voice) has been archived for a while now, but I couldn't find any notice as to why.

Comment: I'm using that bot only for personal use only, im not using to sell it or to put on more servers, so i think is not wrong?

Comment: Yeah, im looking for every corner on internet to know more about, but no one can really explain why isnt working and the majority of the posts are outdated so idk